# Hibernate @Index on @Enumerated field doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, indexing

I am using Hibernate to talk to my DB. I have one field that is an enumeration and it is going to be used in a slow query. So I'd like to index it. I've put the following annotations on the field:

```
@Column(name="RIGHT_TYPE", unique=false, nullable=false, length=10)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Index(name = "ABC_INDEX")
protected RightType rightType;
```

However, I don't see any index on that field created.

I'm using `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect`. The (trimmed down) ddl is:

```
create table DOCUMENTS (documentID varchar2(255 char) not null, owner_principalId varchar2(255 char), primary key (documentID))
create table DOC_RIGHTS (document raw(255) not null, primary key (document))
create table PRINCIPAL (TYPE varchar2(31 char) not null, principalId varchar2(255 char) not null, displayName varchar2(255 char), primary key (principalId))
create table PRINCIPAL_RIGHTS (id varchar2(255 char) not null, PRINCIPAL_ID varchar2(255 char) unique, DOCUMENT_RIGHT_ID raw(255) unique, primary key (id))
create table RIGHTS (TYPE varchar2(31 char) not null, id number(19,0) not null, RIGHT_TYPE varchar2(10 char) not null, PRINCIPAL_RIGHT_ID varchar2(255 char) unique, primary key (id))
create table ROLE_MAP (PRINCIPAL_ID varchar2(255 char) not null, ROLE_ID varchar2(255 char) not null)
alter table DOCUMENTS add constraint FKDC2BB35E362547 foreign key (owner_principalId) references PRINCIPAL
create index PRINCIPAL_INDEX on PRINCIPAL_RIGHTS (PRINCIPAL_ID)
alter table PRINCIPAL_RIGHTS add constraint FKB32239ADFB30571B foreign key (PRINCIPAL_ID) references PRINCIPAL
alter table PRINCIPAL_RIGHTS add constraint FKB32239ADE1F0C813 foreign key (DOCUMENT_RIGHT_ID) references DOC_RIGHTS
create index RIGHT_TYPE_INDEX on RIGHTS (RIGHT_TYPE)
alter table RIGHTS add constraint FKF34FBA9CA09D6215 foreign key (PRINCIPAL_RIGHT_ID) references PRINCIPAL_RIGHTS
alter table ROLE_MAP add constraint FKA413CD78FB30571B foreign key (PRINCIPAL_ID) references PRINCIPAL
alter table ROLE_MAP add constraint FKA413CD7883A04939 foreign key (ROLE_ID) references PRINCIPAL
create sequence RIGHTS_SEQUENCE
```

But I can create one manually if I wish so. Why is that? Is there any way to force Hibernate to make it happen?

Comment: What is your dialect? Can you show the generated DDL?

Comment: Added the requested information in the entry

Comment: Looks like a bug. File an issue at http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work just as you've got in your question. I've created a little [test app](http://github.com/gid79/hibernate-index-test) that demonstrates this working in a standalone app.

One thing that my be happening is that hibernate will not attempt to create indexes during an update operation. It will create them from scratch `hbm2ddl=create` but not during an update. The hibernate teams standard response for this being reported as a bug is 'hbm2ddl is only for development and therefore indexes are not required and you should get a DBA.

My personal recomendation if this is the problem is to start to use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to manage creating things like indexes.

Comment: Changed to create and now the index is there!

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithIndices {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GENDER_TYPE", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 10)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Index(name = "ABC_INDEX")
    protected GenderType genderType;

    // getter and setters
}
```

With the following enum:

```
public enum GenderType {
    FEMALE("0"), MALE("1");

    private final String genderCode;

    public String getCode() {
        return this.genderCode;
    }

    private GenderType(String code) {
        this.genderCode = code;
    }
}
```

And with Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA, MySQL 5.1 as database, the index gets generated. I can't try with Oracle though. I did a [search for existing issues](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=show&createNew=true) (project *z- Hibernate Annotations*, *Any* Issue Type, on "*index*") and couldn't find any recent issue with recent versions of Hibernate annotations (which does not mean there is no problem). If you create an issue, try to provide a simple runnable test case and the SchemaExport logs, this would highly increase your chances to get it fixed.